# wp_set_object_terms() Fails to Set Terms

Tags: taxonomy, terms, wp-insert-post

Okay guys, here's the scenario.

I'm am trying to setup a function that will automatically duplicate a post (when published) over to another post type. So, a regular blog post is published, and when it is published, all of its information is copied over to a custom post type (for WP ECommerce), automatically creating a store entry for that blog post.

I've written a function that takes care of picking up all of the information and inserting it into a new post with wp_insert_post(). It all works great, except for one thing. I'm using wp_set_object_terms() to set the store category ids of the new product based on the tags of the blog post. However, for some reason, wp_set_object_terms() never works.

Now, here's the catch. I'm running all of this on a multi site install and am using [threeWP_Broadcast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) to allow me to cross publish posts. The blog posts (which have to be copied to the store) are published from a sub site and broadcasted to the main site. The store is on the main site.

So I've hooked my custom function into the broadcast plugin so that it gets fired when a post is broadcasted from a sub site to the main site.

Everything with my function works great, except for the wp_set_object_terms()

Here's function:

```
function copy_post_to_store_product() {

global $blog_id;
global $wpdb;

// only copy the post over if on main site, not subsites
if ($blog_id == 1) {

    $args = array('numberposts' => 1);
    $latest = get_posts($args);
    foreach($latest as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

        // if NOT Tip and NOT source avail, create product
        // if source, price is ALWAYS $4
        // auto create for source files only -- regular post type

        $custom_meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);

        // what kind of post is this?
        $post_type = $custom_meta['cgc_post_type'][0];
        // does this post have a source file product associated with it?
        $source_avail = $custom_meta['cgc_source_avail'][0];

        // source file price
        $price = '4';


        $product_info = array(
            'post_title'    => $post->post_title,
            'post_type'     => 'wpsc-product',
            'post_content'  => $post->post_content,
            'post_author'   => $post->post_author,
            'post_status'   => 'draft', 
        );


        if($post_type == 'Regular' && $source_avail == true) {
            // only auto create product for Regular posts that have source files for sale
            $product_id = wp_insert_post($product_info);
            update_post_meta($product_id, '_wpsc_price', $price);

            if (has_tag('blender', $post->ID)) 
            { 
                $product_cats = array(23,32);
            }
            elseif (has_tag('max', $post->ID)) {
                $product_cats = array(23,34);
            }
            elseif (has_tag('modo', $post->ID)) {
                $product_cats = array(23,19);
            }

            // set the product categories
            wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $product_cats, 'wpsc_product_category' );

        }


    endforeach;
}
```

}

The function works by retrieving the latest post from the main site ($blog_id == 1) and copying all of its information into variables for wp_insert_post().

Now, the really interesting thing is that works perfectly if I attach the function to a publish_post hook, but, unfortunately, I can't do that because that hook doesn't fire when a post is broadcasted.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What does `wp_set_object_terms()` return for you?

Comment: Nothing at all, at least not than I can tell. It acts as though it worked, but nothing gets set.

Comment: @Pippin it should always return something (can be different things depending on if it worked and what error is if it didn't), wrap it in `var_dump()`

Comment: @Rarst this is what I'm getting: 

object(WP_Error)#1159 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid Taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: @Rarst I know that the taxonomy name is correct, as well as the IDS, so I really don't understand that error.

Comment: @Pippin well, obviously WP disagrees with you on that... so it's down to figuring out which term errors out and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a solution, but there's a [ticket #20541](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20541) on Make WordPress Core.

Apparently a call to `switch_to_blog()` would not repopulate `$wp_taxomies`, which these taxonomies rely on.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across the same problem and worked out a solution with help from [Patriek's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15570/wp-set-object-terms-fails-to-set-terms/16481#16481). You just need to make sure that `wp_set_object_terms()` is run after the custom taxonomy is registered. Since `register_taxonomy()` is usually run at `init`, you can also run your function at `init` action hook, but with a lower priority so it runs later.

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_taxonomies', 0 );

function register_custom_taxonomies() {
    // register your taxonomies here    
}

add_action( 'init', 'copy_post_to_store_product', 10)

function copy_post_to_store_product() {
    // your function that runs wp_set_object_terms() here
}
```

This way, the taxonomy is guaranteed to be available when your function is run.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the previous answer, You say that it works fine with `publish_post` hook then you create a plugin in your mu-plugins (“must-use” plugins) which you can hook your function to and just add `switch_to_blog` before you start inserting and updating things in the database and then revert back using `restore_current_blog()`
So

```
switch_to_blog($main_blog_id); //usually 1
...
//your function
...
restore_current_blog();
```

Comment: Nope, didn't make any difference

Comment: Ok, i have another idea for you I'll post in a little while.

Comment: @Pippin: I added a new solution.

Comment: I know what you mean by mu-plugins and such, but I'm not sure I'm following how that fixes it . . .

Comment: its not fixing it its doing the same in another way and avoiding the use of threeWP_Broadcast  all together, since you are using every blog's `save_posts` and hooking it to the same function which will work on the main blog.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you.

Comment: Any feedback? Good or bad?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been able to check, but I will first thing in the morning, with plenty of time before the bounty expires.

Comment: I care less about the bounty,  I'm working on a new project which requires something similar and i wanted to know if it worked out for you :)

Comment: Well I'm having a hard time telling if it's going to work or not. Your idea does seem to work, but wp_set_object_terms is dumping an error:

object(WP_Error)#1159 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid Taxonomy" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Comment: Without seeing the code it's a shot in the dark but make sure Taxonomy Name in your `register_taxonomy` arguments array is all **LOWERCASE** . if that is not the case it I'd be glad to take a look at the code and help you out.

Comment: The taxonomy is from wp ecommerce.

This is the url of wp-admin when viewing the taxonomy: "?taxonomy=wpsc_product_category&post_type=wpsc-product"

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there: I had a similar problem once where a taxonomy was not available at the time my function was running. This could either be a problem with wp ecommerce or the broadcast plugin.

Check if the wp ecommerce plugin uses this syntax for registering their taxonomy

```
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomy_function_name', 0 );
```

Check if they appended the ,0. This sets the  priority of the taxonomy function to 0. Which would be as early as possible.

Is it possible to set priority for the broadcast hook?

Comment: WP eCommerce is using that format, but they have set a priority of 8. But I don't think this could have anything to do with it, could it? The plugin is active and functioning fine at the time I am trying to use wp_set_object_terms

Comment: It can if the broadcast plugin functions before the taxonomy exists, you will get the invalid taxonomy i think

Comment: I understand that. But the taxonomy exists once the plugin has been activated. The broadcast function only takes place after publishing a post, which only happens in this case after the plugin has been activated and in use for a while

Comment: depends at which hook the post intercept is called, you can try setting the tax to 0 see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

i have got the solution,

i have investigated the `taxonomy.php` file, then i found that the problem is on the function `taxonomy_exists()`. Since the `switch_to_blog()` function don't read the theme and plugin code, so it will not detect our registered taxonomy on the other blog, so we need to manualy init that, just before the `taxonomy_exists()` function

Put this code before the `wp_set_object_terms()` function:

```
global $wp_taxonomies;
$wp_taxonomies['your_blog_taxonomy'] = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying so much trial and error I have found the real issue is that you need to set your function of setting up a taxonomy for CTP in Init with low priority.

`add_action( 'init', 'your_function_product', 20 );`

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, you saved my life :)
Low priority (20) for the function that inserts the post(s) will do the trick!
Here is an approach for **wp_insert_post()** in *functions.php:*

```
function insert_db_posts() {
        $thepost = wp_insert_post(array(
                'post_type'         =>  'art',
                'post_title'        =>  'Try hard',
                ));
        wp_set_object_terms( $thepost, 37, 'artist');
}
add_action( 'init', 'insert_db_posts', 20 ); // this will fire very late so everything else is already initialized before this!!!
```